# How to obtain Visual Studio compiler options without performing a build?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Is it possible to obtain the Visual Studio compiler options without running a build? Or at most a dry/simulated build?

This information is available in Visual Studio via the menu selection "Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line". See the screenshot below. However, I would like to have this information available automatically because I need it in a command line tool. This should preferably work both for C/C++ and C#.

[image]

Comment: All of the information is available in the project file - unfortunately this is an XML file & the options use tags that you would have to know how to convert to the appropriate option string (e.g. quite easy is _<WarningLevel>Level1</WarningLevel>_ translates to _/W1_, less easy is _<Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>_ translates to _/O2_)

Comment: @PaulF, thanks. This is what I tried in the past. However, a lot of options are undocumented or very hard to extract e.g. by consulting all kinds of inherited property sheets. So that is not the way to go I think.

Comment: As it is the way that Visual Studio stores the values then I don't think there are any other easy options.

Comment: Why do you need the compiler parameters? Usually, you'd just run MSBuild on the project/solution file.

Comment: @Luaan. We use this information to instrument third party code checkers. Some code checkers need to know the location of the C# assemblies others need to get all compiler flags to preprocess the C/C++ code etc.